# AES vs 3DES for NFC device authentication (Mifare)

Tags: android, security, aes, nfc, 3des

I'm in a situation where i have to choose between two types of cards,
Mifare Ultralight C and Mifare Plus. Former offers 3DES and the latter, AES. QUite obviously, security is a must and is important in the given circumstance.

1. On what basis do i select the technology?
2. If possible, do you know how it can be used through the Android SDK?
3. Please keep in mind ultimately i would like to move into Payments through the usage of NFC. Does this change the dynamics of the selection criteria?

Thanks

Comment: You can also add your own security layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some facts that may help in your decision:

- MIFARE Plus has 3 possible Security Levels (depending on the exact type of MIFARE Plus IC). Security Level 2 cannot be accessed by the Android NFC API.
- MIFARE Plus, although it is Android `IsoDep` compatible, is not ISO 7816 compatible
- Communication between phone and MIFARE Ultralight C (and v.v.) is never encrypted.
- MIFARE Ultralight C has very limited storage capability
- MIFARE DESFire EV1 offers 3DES and AES authentication and communication encryption, offers ISO 7816 compatibility, is NFC Forum compliant and available in 2K, 4K and 8K variants.

Comment: Thank You! Does this mean i cannot use MifareClassic class in android to interact with the Mifare Plus card?

Comment: You can for MIFARE PLus configured to Security Level 1 (as that is backwards compatible to MIFARE Classic), it will show up as having `MifareClassic` technology. In Security Level 3, it will show up as having `IsoDep` technology, and you can communicate with it. Only Security Level 2 is a problem: it will show up as `NfcA`, but you won't be able to communicate with it in any useful way.

Comment: @NFC guy: I also encountered some weird situation with Mifare Plus security level 1 and 2 - not on Android however. Could you please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740868/communicating-with-mifare-plus-with-win-32-api? Particularly I am interested if it is possible to communicate with the card which is in Level 1 and 2 using Win 32 API? (with 0 and 3 level I think it's possible). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that according to the [Mifare Ultralight C documentation](http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf) the DES implementation is a 2-key DES only (and not a 3-key DES) I would prefer the AES capable card.